# What is the best way to implement an HTTP endpoint with different return types?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-api

I need to make an HTTP endpoint with different return types based on query params. There are several options to do that:

Return an object with one property set and the rest equal to null:

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    Type1 Property1 { set; get; }
    Type2 Property2 { set; get; }
    Type3 Property3 { set; get; }
}

...

return new ResponseModel { Field2 = responseObj };
```

Return an object with enum or string indicating the return type and a string with jsonified object:

```
public enum ReturnType
{
    Type1, Type2, Type3
}

public class ResponseModel
{
    ReturnType Type { set; get; }
    string Payload { set; get; }
}

...

return new ResponseModel { Type = ReturnType.Type2, Payload = responseObj.Jsonify() };
```

I might be able to come up with other solutions, however, I would like to know if there are any general recommendations and/or best practices when implementing such an endpoint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: c# forces you to have a single type on whatever service method you are exposing, so why are you exposing three methods behind a single endpoint?

Comment: If all the responses are essentialy the same thing (*is-a*) you could use inheritance instead of composition. Maybe I'm biased by the so many REST API I do in my job, but my recommendation would be *don't go that way*. Keep the things as simple as possible, even if that means to duplicate some lines of code.

Comment: If the responses really are the same thing, but you want to return it in a different format, then content negotiation might be what you are looking for.

Comment: This might be more at home on stack overflow

Comment: Presumably, youre attempting to serialise an object hierarchy into a single JSON model?